# Was there a time skip on episode 2 of Tokyo Ghoul Season 2?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

I just notice that Touka has changed and became more mature. Her surroundings, including Hide who has a part time job, have also changed/became more mature.
How many years have passed? Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is "a years time skip". At most a few months have passed, as the Anti-Ghoul members who were injured have healed and Aogiri have taken over some areas.

At this point in the manga, the time skip was around 6 months, but apparently this is an original story (for season 2) so that may not be a good guideline.